# Можно ли выполнить код перед удалением приложения

Tags: java, android

Мне во время делания приложения понадобилось очищать значения getSharedPreferences перед удалением. Я обрыскал все сайты, и никто не обсуждал и не говорил об этом.
Кто знает, пожалуйста напишите как очистить getSharedPreferences перед удалением

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь то при удалении приложения папка тоже удаляется, в самом приложении вы вряд ли сможете отловить удаление

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как очистить getSharedPreferences перед удалением

SharedPreferences автоматически удаляется при удалении приложения. Специально очищать его не требуется.

Comment: Я сам смотрел, что при удалении приложения SharedPreferеnces не удаляется

Comment: @JAVAJSHTMLCSS, может проблема не в том что не удаляется, а в том как вы это проверяете?